# Create New Parameter

Tags: streamsets

Trying to create a new parameter in StreamSets and I am getting this error >

[image]

I am following exactly the official tutorial, but it seems this validation is new!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior for handling pipeline parameters has not changed recently.

Looking at the image you provided, the parameter is not specified correctly. You have $(p_batch_size); the correct format for the parameter is ${p_batch_size}. Try replacing the parentheses with braces.